# How to set Fancybox position

Tags: jquery-ui, fancybox

I'm using fancybox in a very long page with a long scrollbar.

The fancybox loads at the center of this page and so see it only if you scroll.

How do I do to load the fancybox at the start of page?

Answer (score 0):

Use property `centerOnScroll = true`